# Any JS library for date range slider with populated data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

I am trying to find a javascript library that does a horizontal calendar that you can populate data into. The design I have is like this image:

```
It is similar to calendars that flight companies provide (like british airways or air canada).
```

The only example I could find with JS is this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vM844/1236/) that uses JQRangeSlider.

Are there any libraries that can be used to develop my design?

[image: Date Range Slider]

Comment: As per the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), questions just asking for library recommendations are not on topic for this site. Is there a specific problem you're having? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) is one of the useful JavaScript libraries for time development.